# Django urlpattern with infinite number of parameters

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, url-pattern

Is it possible to define Django urlpattern, which would get any number of same type parameters and pass them to a view?

Lets say I want to create a page which gets a list of numbers from url and sums them. So these would be valid urls:

```
/sum/10/99/12/
/sum/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/
/sum/3/
```

I guess that view could look like this:

```
def sum_view(request, *args):
    return render(request, 'sum.html', {'result': sum(args)})
```

Question is how should urlpattern look like? Maybe something like this:

```
url(r'^sum/((\d+)/)+$', views.sum_view)
```

But this way view gets only last number repeated twice: `args == ('1/', '1')`. What is the correct regular expression to get all the numbers passed ot the view?

Comment: Why don't you pass params in GET format? -> `/sum/?nums=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could capture a single argument, e.g. `'1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/'`

```
url(r'^sum/(?P<numbers>[\d/]+)$', views.sum_view)
```

The split the list in the view.

```
def sum_view(request, numbers):
    processed_numbers = [int(x) for x in number.split('/') if x]
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Django's urlpatterns are based on python's regexps so there is no way of catching all data from repeating group. Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30097158/regex-with-repeating-groups) for explanation.

You will have to split and process them by yourself (like @Alasdair suggests).