# The current path, book/1/2/3/4/5/6/, didn’t match any of these

Tags: django, django-views

I've Created a view

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('book/<suffix>/', views.bookview, name='bookDetail')`
]
```

what i want

- if someone hits url `'127.0.0.1:8000/book/1/2/3/4/5/6/'`
- i do not want django to raise an error of `The current path,  book/1/2/3/4/5/6/, didn’t match any of these.`
- but instead it shows the same view of url `book/<suffix>/` which is `view.bookview`.
- and somehow pass, suffix after `book/` which is `1/2/3/4/5/6/` as arg so that i can access it in my view.

Comment: Try to use `<str:suffix>`

Comment: still not working

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555195/django-urlpattern-with-infinite-number-of-parameters

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How one can capture string that contain one or more forward slash in django urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68251393/how-one-can-capture-string-that-contain-one-or-more-forward-slash-in-django-urls)

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^book/(?P<suffix>[\w/]+)$', views.bookview, name='bookDetail')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As there can be special characters in the `suffix` parameter, you need to encode the string. In python you can do it like this

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
suffix = quote_plus('/1/2/3/4/5/6/')
```